# Eclipse 2021.12 does not work with multimodule projects

Tags: eclipse, gradle

Unlike Eclipse Oxygen, Eclipse 2021.12 does not seem to recognize multimodule springboot projects.  Java Run does not appear for the main program.  I cannot screenshare the project.

Comment: Of course it can. With so little information, it's hard to tell what you did wrong. There is no Eclipse 2121.12, the current version is 2022-03 (which means March 2022). Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry it is 2021.12

Comment: I guess you mean 2021-12, but I cannot guess what you did wrong. Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example